# ­«El resto de regiones», ¿se puede omitir el segundo artículo en las expresiones partitivas?

Tags: gramática, artículos

Editando un documento en Word me he dado cuenta de que me solía marcar como erróneas frases como la siguiente:

> *Pijama* es una palabra masculina en algunas regiones, como España y el cono sur de América, mientras que en **el resto de regiones** se usa como femenino.

Según el corrector del Word, la expresión marcada en negrita sería incorrecta, puesto que debería ser *el resto de las regiones*, incluyendo el segundo artículo. ¿Es, por tanto, incorrecta la omisión de ese segundo artículo?

Answer (score 3):

Como ya sabemos, que algo sea correcto o incorrecto es relativo. Consulté a la RAE a este respecto en Twitter y su respuesta ha sido [la siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1275304811488071681):

> Pese a la tendencia que se aprecia en la lengua actual a prescindir del artículo en las estructuras partitivas, se recomienda no omitirlo.

Enlaza además al [párrafo 20.2j](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wnEZyCjksEQISWWs) de la *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española*, que amplía dicha información:

> [...] se describe la tendencia que se aprecia en la lengua actual a prescindir del artículo en las estructuras partitivas con las expresiones nominales *la mayoría* y *la mayor parte* (*la mayoría de ciudadanos* por *la mayoría de los ciudadanos*; *la mayor parte de ideas* por *la mayor parte de las ideas*) y se explica que no se recomienda la variante sin artículo.

En el [párrafo 14.7b](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SucKsRAzYZiEiWIR) se apunta, además:

> Cabe pensar, por el contrario, que el rasgo de definitud presente en *la mayoría* es el que activa, en la conciencia lingüística de algunos hablantes, la supresión del artículo en la coda partitiva (*la mayoría de las propiedades* > *la mayoría de propiedades*) de forma similar a como lo hace en las relativas especificativas preposicionales: *el libro con el que estudio* > *el libro con que estudio*.

Y en el [párrafo 21.6l](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bGEtZjkOvjmIlAkz) se amplía la información:

> [...] se percibe una marcada tendencia en la lengua actual a prescindir del artículo en las construcciones partitivas en expresiones nominales fraccionarias como *la mayoría de...*, *la mayor parte de...*, *un tercio de...*, *la mitad de...*, etc. Se registran, pues, *la mayoría de alumnos*, por *la mayoría de los alumnos*; *la mayor parte de accidentes*, por *la mayor parte de los accidentes*. Aunque pudiera pensarse que la omisión del artículo convierte la construcción partitiva en pseudopartitiva, no se obtiene el significado que corresponde a esta última. En cualquier caso, puede haber influido en el proceso el que los sustantivos fraccionarios, que solo admiten la construcción partitiva (*un tercio de los ciudadanos*), se asimilen en la conciencia lingüística de algunos hablantes a los numerales colectivos, que admiten la pseudopartitiva (*un millón de ciudadanos*).

Resumiendo: la RAE aconseja no omitir el artículo de la coda partitiva, aunque reconoce que hay una marcada tendencia a omitirlo en algunas de estas construcciones.